# How can I protect a protruding spigot pipe from impact damage?

Tags: spigot

The photo shows a vulnerable PVC pipe emanating from a wall in Florida.   Is there a mechanism to protect it?  Box or other some other clever means?

The concern is that the PVC will snap and it would be very difficult to repair / replace.  I am thinking that an ounce of prevention is better than a pound of cure.

“Less is more” in an Condo HOA

[image]

Comment: How much protection do want?  Just something people will see and not bump into it, or something that can take a bump?  Problem is in the future work will be needed on it, plus you want it easy to be used.  Could just place a small plastic bucket on it, or make a frame of 1x3s around the opening to screw a box on.  A box made from 1/4 inch steel plate should protect it quite well.

Comment: From freezing there are insulting covers…

Comment: Take look at something called **split** flange,. It comes in two halves that go around the pipe and can be screwed in the wall to provide some additional protection.

Comment: A wall mounted hose hanger should work also, be a bit low.

Comment: Is this a rental home? If so, you'd have to get the landlord's permission to attach things to the wall. If not, the best protection is replacement: Get a metal through-the-wall spigot so the PVC pipe is inside the house completely. Example: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-x-3-4-in-x-8-in-MPT-SWT-x-MHT-Brass-Anti-Siphon-Frost-Free-Sillcock-Valve-with-Multi-Turn-Operation-104-515EB/205821741 (just saw that @FreeMan suggested this idea on the answer below, too.)

Comment: I note your recent edit. If the condo HOA won't approve a hose rack or replacement of the PVC with metal, then they can deal with the flooding when someone manages to break off the PVC pipe.... #noseybusybodies >:(

Answer (score 2):

Take a 3-5 gallon (12-20 liter) bucket (spend money or not depending on your available used bucket sources and how parsimonious you are or are not. A previously used one is fine. A new one is fine on all fronts except you'll be cutting a hole in the bottom of a perfectly good new bucket you paid for.)

Cut a hole in the bottom large enough to pass the whole spigot through. Drill 3 holes around the edges of the bucket bottom, and drill matching holes for screw anchors in the wall. Slip the bucket over the spigot and screw it to the wall.

It will also serve as a place to coil your hose on, if you like. You could also build stub walls on either side of the spigot to protect it instead, but that's a good deal more trouble and expense.

Comment: Bucket is Great idea, terrible look.

Comment: Feel free to buy a nice designer Champagne bucket, for that classy look. Many hose spigots are, on the other hand, located where looks are secondary to function. If it were my wall, I'd junk the fragile plastic and replace it with a metal, through-wall, freeze-proof (because it freezes where I live) sillcock, that would be inherently less fragile. But the question is about protecting the fragile (and not very attractive, itself) plastic spigot.

Comment: I like the yard hydrant not attached to the house and actually located in the garden of if you have to then the commercial almost flush hose bibs like the Zurn Z1333-C.

Comment: Aquor Wall Hydrant V2+ is also quite nice but pricey !

Comment: Even though this is in FL where freeze events are few & far between (but make entertaining TV for the rest of us), the metal, through-the-wall freeze-proof spigot would make sense, simply because it would be metal protruding through the wall instead of PVC and would be less prone to damage. An alternative to the 5-gallon paint bucket would be a simple hose hanger (of any decorative sort) mounted above the spigot with the hose coiled around it.

Answer (score 1):

**Put a post in the ground.**

It could even have a rack for your hose. I'd come out just past the spigot and slightly to one side. It could also be a flower or bird feeder hanger.